# ¿Cómo reemplazar la función get_file_content por cURL?

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

Estoy utilizando la librería Simple HTML DOM Parser para extraer unas líneas de código, pero estoy decepcionado porque esta librería trabaja con la función `file_get_contents`, la cual en algunos sitios está desactivada por razones de seguridad, pero en su lugar sugieren utilizar curl.

Mi pregunta es: ¿se puede adaptar dicha librería para trabajar con curl y que funcione exactamente igual?

Código fuente **simple_dom_html.php**

```
//Lineas de codigo donde aparece la funcion que deseo remplazar con Curl
$contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);

//Esta es la ultima vez que la libreria utiliza File_get_content
function load_file() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $this->load(call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args), true);
    // Throw an error if we can't properly load the dom.
    if (($error=error_get_last())!==null) {
        $this->clear();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Según lo que he leído el sustituto para mi problema sería sacar el texto con curl ya que realiza exactamente la misma función, sería algo así:

```
$site_url = 'http://example.com';
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5; // set to zero for no timeout
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
ob_start();
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$file_contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $file_contents;
```

Answer (score 3):

Si puedes trabajar con CURL en **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**. Puedes usar una rutina como esta:

```
<?
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'http://www.pagina.com/';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($curl_scraped_page, true, false);


foreach($html->find('head') as $d) {
    $d->innertext = "<base href='$url'>" . $d->innertext;
}

echo $html->save();

?>
```

Ahora, si no te resulta es posible que tengas algún problema como el que se plantea en la consulta *Problem with hosting*  de este link: [ http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_faq.htm ] . Veamos si te ayuda.

Comment: Hola @eduardomunizaga Amigo muchas gracias por su respuesta, Pero en efecto no funciono.. Probe implementarlo de la manera mencionada el script queda en espera y no retorna ningún resultado, verifique si mi hosting soporta cURL y si esta activo, así que no comprendo porque no funciona lei el enlace que tiene el mismo problema y exacto en mi hosting allow_url_fopen" "php.ini"  ESTA desactivado, pero me dijeron que curl hace lo mismo así que por eso creo que tendría que modificar simple_dom_html.php porque la librería por defecto utiliza file_get_contents

Comment: Yo de todas formas Activaría el *allow_url_fopen* con el fin de comprobar la teoría y si resulta ya sabes de que se trata. Para estas cosas hay que creerse científico y utilizar el método de descarte.

Comment: Mi proveedor de hosting ya me dijo que 'allow_url_fopen' esta desactivado así que al parecer DOM no trabaja si el , que mal royo

Comment: Muy mal, porque desde la versión PHP 5.3.0:  ya no puedes usar  ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true); .

Comment: Odio cURL nunca lo he podido utilizar.

Answer (score 0):

También puedes utilizar `file_get_html($url);`

Saludos